# MySQL Query Not Working Live But Works In PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check my 'Users' MySQL table to see if a user exists I am using the code below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = 'user' AND `password` = '5e8a94e952c5b6767fab70b75d380beae921334e'
```

```
$result = mysqli_query($accountCon,$sql);
mysqli_close($accountCon);
```

When I run this code in phpMyAdmin the code runs fine and returns one user like it should. In my *.php script I am connecting to the server like this:

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "database";
$mysql_user = "username";
$mysql_password = "password";
$accountCon=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

This does not return an error so I can only assume that it connected to server. I have similar code through out my website for creating accounts and updating tokens etc. Since the query working in phpMyAdmin I know the table is setup correctly.

Other attempts:

```
$result = $accountCon->query($sql); //same error
```

Comment: How you are executing your query. Update that code also in the question

Comment: is the table Users exists in your live databse?

Comment: Show us the code, where you are executing the query

Comment: @AlexPelletier I edited the username and password out of your question. Even if that's just your localhost config, it would still be better to filter it.

Comment: Can you try running the query like this?  `$accountCon->query( "select * from user ... " )`

Comment: @Passerby thanks, I tend to over share information.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I just tried $result = $accountCon->query($sql); same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of testing and working on other parts of the site I have figured out the problem. The problem was that I was not closing a mySQL connection in my functions.php file.

Fix:

```
mysqli_close($accountCon);
```

The moral of this is that you always need to close your mySQL connections. . .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this code ...

```
$mysql_host     = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "dbname";     //It dbname is your actual database name.
$mysql_user     = "root";       //Phpmyadmin default user name is root.
$mysql_password = "";           //By default there is no password used in phpmyadmin.
$accountCon=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Now you run your query like this on same script.

```
$query = $accountCon->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='user' AND password='5e8a94e952c5b6767fab70b75d380beae921334e'");
echo $query->num_rows ;
```

Try it.

Thanks

Comment: I have changed query, and it is running on my localhost wamp server. Now you please try again.